# Convergence of $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+1}-1$ to $0$ on $(-1, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I was able to show that the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+1}-1$ is increasing for any $x_0\in(-1, 0)$ and that $0$ is an upper bound for it, but how does one prove that it converges to $0$ for every $x_0\in(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R, x\to \sqrt{x+1}-1$

Note that $\forall x\geq 0, f(x)\leq x$ and $f$ is increasing.

Prove next that $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_n$ is increasing, and $0 \ge x_n \ge x_0 > -1$, so $x_n \to x$ and $ x \ge x_0 > -1$. Take the limit in the equation $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}+1}-1$, we have
$$x = \sqrt{x + 1} - 1$$,
Solve for x, we have two solutions: $ x = 0$ or $x = -1$. But $ x > -1$, so $x =0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y_n=1+x_n$, then $y_{n+1}=\sqrt{y_n}$ and thus
$$
y_n=(y_0)^{2^{-n}}
$$
which converges to $(y_0)^0=1$ if $y_0>0$, i.e., $x_n\to 0$ for $x_0>-1$.